# Terminate a process and close all its opened listening ports

Tags: c++, qt, port

On my Qt application, I run an external executable on a separate process like this:

```
QProcess *server = new QProcess();
server->start("./server.exe");
```

External executable starts a server on `127.0.0.1` listening on port `18383`.

Then at some point, I terminate the process like this:

```
server->terminate();
```

The problem is that by terminating the server process, many times its used port i.e. `18383` remains open. Consequently, when I try to start the server again, I receive these errors:

> "Server -2 Could not setup server. listen tcp :18383: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

How can I terminate the process and close all its opened listening ports?

Comment: Does the terminate() call actually kill the process?

Comment: @Michael Well, sometimes I receive these errors while terminating the process: `QProcess: Destroyed while process (" ... server.exe ...") is still running`

Comment: In that case, the process object is destroyed while the actual process is still running.    You should try a graceful exit instead.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! I'm going to study `QProcess` documentation more to see if I can use its API for a graceful exit.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](/questions/37292063/what-is-the-meaning-of-time-wait-state-in-windows-when-i-entered-netstat-na-i)

Comment: If under Windows, Qt is way outdated anyway.

Comment: Try opening your port with `SO_REUSEADDR`, you might just be encountering the situation where the listening port is kept open for a short while to allow for in flight tcp packets to be received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sometimes I receive these errors while terminating the process:
>   QProcess: Destroyed while process (" ... server.exe ...") is still
>   running

It seems you are not waiting for the process to gracefully terminate.
Here is a generic way to terminate a process you launched :

```
server->terminate(); 
server->waitForFinished(timeoutMS);
if (server->state() == QProcess::Running) {
     server->kill();
}
```

Terminate will send a polite "can you please stop" signal, kill will abruptly stop the target process. How much time does it take for the server to shut down (it may be several seconds)? so you should have a generous timeout period which take this in account.

Comment: Thanks! The error `QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running` got resolved :) However, I'm not sure if I will receive the `Server -2` error on tcp port again. I hope I won't!

Comment: if the server is not leaking network resources it should be fine.